# Apache poi SpreadSheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

Meu código ao gerar uma planilha dentro de um arquivo do excel ele apaga as outras todas, como eu faço para ele criar a planilha em 2° sem que ela apague as outras?

Meu código:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class Apache {

   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {


      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 


      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("workbook.ods");

      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("teste 2");

      workbook.write(out);
      out.close();
      System.out.println("workbook.ods");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece por que você está sempre substituindo os dados do arquivo, ao invés de carregá-los e alterá-los.

**Exemplo com arquivo xlsx:**

Note que na primeira linha eu instancio um Workbook com base em um arquivo existente.

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("caminho arquivo xlsx"));

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("caminho arquivo xlsx");

    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("teste 2");

    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
```

**Obs:** Se você tentar criar um Sheet com um nome que já existe, irá gerar uma exceção.